# How to check the class name of the event target in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-dom, classname

[image]

I now have a function `handleRightClick(e)` which will be called when I right click on the container. Inside the container, there are several `Item`s and I expect the menu will be shown only when I right click one of the `Item`s.

```
export default class ProjectContainer extends React.Component {
    ...
    handleRightClick(e) {
        console.log(e.target.name); // I want to check the event target whether is `Item` Class.
        this.refs.rightClickMenu.reShow(e.clientX, e.clientY); // This will open the right click menu.
    }
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={styles.root} onContextMenu={this.handleRightClick} onClick={this.handleLeftClick}>
                <Item /><Item /><Item /><Item /><Item /><Item /><Item />
                <RightClickMenuForProjectItem ref='rightClickMenu'/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If I `console.log(e)`, I get this in Chrome console:

```
> Object {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, _dispatchInstances: ReactDOMComponent, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "contextmenu"…}
```

This is the class `Item`:

```
export default class Item extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Card style={styles.card} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                <img style={styles.img}/>
                <div style={styles.divInfo}>
                    <h4 style={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</h4>
                    <div style={styles.projectType}>{this.props.projectType}</div>
                </div>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Finally, I will use it to form something like this:

```
handleRightClick(e) {
    if (e.target.className == "Item") {
        // Open the right click menu only when I right click one of the Item.
        this.refs.rightClickMenu.reShow(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
}
```

I want to check the event target whether is `Item` class. How can I access the class name of the event target?

Comment: You need access to a `className` or name of the component? i'm confused

Comment: I updated my question. I want to access the class name which is called `Item` of a class extends `React.Component`

Comment: How is the class being set initially? Is it dynamic?

Comment: Check `e.target.classList` too

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To access at `className` an element use `e.target.className`

Try with this

```
export default class ProjectContainer extends React.Component {
    ...
    handleRightClick(e) {
        // To avoid get wrong class name, use this.
        // But if the default context menu come up, without this is OK.
        e.stopPropagation()
        console.log(e.target.className); // This get the className of the target
        this.refs.rightClickMenu.reShow(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the same on javascript without lib's

If an empty result is appeared in the console, this means that you haven't set the `className` of the `Item` class in the render return. You can change your class to be like this:

```
const className = 'Item';
export default class Project extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
            return (
                <Card style={styles.card} onClick={this.props.onClick} className={className}>
                    <img style={styles.img} className={className}/>
                    <div style={styles.divInfo} className={className}>
                        <h4 style={styles.title} className={className}>{this.props.title}</h4>
                        <div style={styles.projectType} className={className}>{this.props.projectType}</div>
                    </div>
                </Card>
            );
    }
}
```

Now the resulting `handleRightClick(e)` should be like this:

```
handleRightClick(e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'Item')
        //Show the menu if it is not visible, reShow the menu if it is already visible
        this.refs.rightClickMenu.reShow(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    else
        //Hide the menu
        this.refs.rightClickMenu.hide();
}
```

#### Result

The menu will be shown when click one of the `Item`.
[image]

The menu will not be shown when click outside the `Item`.
[image]

Comment: You are right, but it gives me `IMG` or `H4` or `DIV`. These results are too detailed.

Comment: use `stopPropagation()` to get the className of your element clicked not their parents.

Comment: If I `call stopPropagation()`, the default context menu from chrome come out and I still get `IMG`, `H4` or `DIV`.

Comment: @CasperLI if you use `e.target.className` your result is the className (.className), if you use `e.target.nodeName` your result is 'LI', 'IMG', 'DIV'

Comment: If I use `e.target.className`, an empty result appears in the console.

Comment: @CasperLI ok, but your need (before) set className attribute to your element. show me the `return()`lines into your react code to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116910/discussion-between-casper-li-and-rui-costa).